# I cannot click on this button using Selenium no matter what Locator I use

Tags: selenium, xpath, testng, href, findby

I cannot click on this button no matter what locator I use and I'm having trouble understanding why. I've used linkText, partialLinkText, x-path, className, etc. I'm using PageFactory in a Page Object Model design pattern.

Here is the code for the div the button is in:

```
<div class="clearfix main-page-indent">
<a href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=address" title="Add an address" class="btn btn-default button button-medium">.   <span>Add a new address<i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i></span></a>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the source code:
view-source:http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=addresses

You just have to create an account first, its super quick.

Here are two of the methods I have tried:

1.)

```
//Page Factory
@FindBy(how = How.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, using = "Add an address")
WebElement newAddressBtn;

public AddNewAddressPage clickAddNewAddressBtn() {
    newAddressBtn.click();
    return new AddNewAddressPage();
}
```

2.)

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@href='http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=address']")
WebElement newAddressBtn;
```

Anyone have any idea how to consolidate this locator?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Right off the bat, it's not going to find a partial link text of "Add an address" when the actual link text according to your HTML is "Add a new address" but even then, that text is within span tags.

Comment: Is this HTML snippet within an IFRAME?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thank you for your suggestions but I found my error. It was not that the locator could not be resolved, but rather I was getting a null pointer exception because I failed to initialize my PageFactory variables. I added this constructor to fix the problem. That way when the page class is instantiated all of the WebElements will be initialized.

```
public MyAddressesPage() {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below xpath to locate your element?

```
    @FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='center_column']/div[2]/a")
    public WebElement addressNew;
```